# how to hide button in customView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib, custom-view

I want to hide button which is on 3rd row when click on the screen this screen contain three rows. i have added touch events and tried with tap gesture but only when i click the 3rd row then button hides if i click on other rows or click on the any place of screen nothing happens.
The main problem  is when i click on 3rd row then button disappears it should be hidden we click any place on screen or click on any cell.
I am using customView showing that view in tablewView. TableView is separate class and custom view is separate class. i am handling button in custom view class.

[image]

Please tell me solution, here is my code

```
class MicTestView: UIView  {

// MARK:-
// MARK:- Properties

// MARK:- IBOutlets

@IBOutlet weak var aidStatusImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

// MARK:- Class Properties

var micLocation : MicLocation = .bottom
let customInfoView = CustominfoView()

var customView = UIView()

// MARK:-
// MARK:- Methods

// MARK: UIView Methods

required init(coder aDecoder : NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder :aDecoder)!
    setup()
}

override init(frame : CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

func setup() {
    let view = loadViewFromXib()
    view.frame = bounds
    // view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight

    addSubview(view)

    progressView.progress = 0
    progressView.transform = progressView.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: (view.superview?.bounds.height)!/2)
    progressView.isHidden = true
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

func loadViewFromXib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "MicTestView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
}

// MARK:- IBActions
@IBAction func infoBtnpressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    customInfoView.isHidden = false

    let customView = customInfoView
    customView.frame = CGRect(x: ((window?.frame.origin.x)! + 60), y: ((window?.frame.origin.y)! + 300), width: 255, height: 200)
    window?.addSubview(customView)
    print("Pressed")

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        self.customInfoView.isHidden = true
    }
}

// MARK: UIViewController overrides
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    self.infoBtn.isHidden = true
    self.customInfoView.isHidden = true
    startRecording()

}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    //
}
```

Comment: you can use protocol delegate to hide the button in the uitableview.

Comment: please give me example with code

Answer (score 0):

Custom Cell

```
protocol tappedDelegate: class {
    func buttonTapped(indexpath: NSIndexPath,btnChange: UIButton)
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate: tappedDelegate?
    var  indexpath1 = NSIndexPath()
    var isOn = Bool()

    @IBOutlet weak var btnClick: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    @IBAction func someButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        let btnImag = btnClick.image(for: .normal)

        if btnImag == UIImage (named: "close") {
            btnClick .setImage(UIImage(named: "buttn"), for: .normal)
        }else
        {
            btnClick .setImage(UIImage(named: "close"), for: .normal)

        }

        self.delegate?.buttonTapped(indexpath: indexpath1, btnChange: btnClick)
    }

class ViewController: UIViewController , tappedDelegate


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "CustomCell"


        var cell: CustomCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? CustomCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? CustomCell
        }

        cell.delegate = self
        cell.indexpath1 = indexPath as NSIndexPath

        return cell
    }
    func buttonTapped(indexpath: NSIndexPath, btnChange: UIButton) {

   // btnChange .setImage(UIImage(named: "buttn"), for: .normal)

    }
```

Comment: Always include explanation for the solution, not just the code!